# How to use Global Variable across all functions in a Controller file - Laravel

Tags: laravel, variables, controller, global-variables, laravel-8

I have a variable **GlobalVariable**  which I want to call in other funcitons to.
As it is with If Case, I cannot go for Config method to call the varibale.

```
  if (config('app.locale')=='en') 
        {
           $GlobalVariable = 'Apple';
        }
  else 
       {
         $GlobalVariable = 'Orange';
       }
```

__construct function is already here for another purpose.
I want to call the above variable **GlobalVariable** in function show and maybe others.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Helper;
use Image;
use DB;

class ImagesController extends Controller 

    {
        public function __construct( AdminSettings $settings, Request $request) 
            {
                $this->settings = $settings::first();
                $this->request = $request;
                
            }

        public function show()
            {
                $title = $GlobalVariable;
                $title_es = $GlobalVariable2;
            }
            return view('images.show', 
                    compact('title','title_es'))
                ->withResponse($response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of [laravel singletons](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#binding-a-singleton), inside your service provider, inside the register method add:

```php
$this->app->singleton('getFruit', function ($app) {
    if (config('app.locale') == 'en') {
        return 'Apple';
    } else {
        return 'Orange';
    }
});
```

this function will be executed just one time in the request, then you can call it anywhere by:

```php
$globalVar = app('getFruit');
```